# PHP mail redirect header location based on nested if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, email, redirect

Hello I am designing a website for a client.
I have designed this form

```
    <form action="inc/email.php" method="POST" onSubmit="alert('Email send successfully!');">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" id="contact-name" name="contact-name" value="" placeholder="Your name" required/>
        <input type="email" id="contact-email" name="contact-email" value="" placeholder="Your email" required/>
        <input type="number" id="contact-phone" name="contact-phone" value="" placeholder="Your phone" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="cars">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Send message"/></td>
    </div>
</form>
```

It has 3 options to select from 1st Volvo, 2nd Saab and 3rd Audi
Now i want to redirect form submission based on user selection to different websites
e.g. facebook.com if user selects Volvo, Twiiter.com if he selects Saab.
I have designed following PHP code for same

```
<?php
/*Getting submitted values from html form*/

$name = $_POST['contact-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$phone = $_POST['contact-phone'];
$cars= $_POST['cars'];
/* Generating Output HTML */

$output = '<html><body><div>';
$output .= '<h2 style="color: #49A020;">Newsletter Email</h2>';
$output .= '<p style="line-height: 28px;font-size: 16px; text-align: justify; color: #333;">Name: '.$name.'</p>';
$output .= 'Phone: <a style="line-height: 28px;font-size: 16px; text-align: justify; color: #333;" href="tel: '.$phone.'">'.$phone.'</a><br><br>';
$output .= 'Email: <a  style="line-height: 28px;font-size: 16px; text-align: justify; color: #333;" href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a>';
$output .= '</div><div>';

/*Signature */

$output .= '<hr style="border:1px solid #49A020;">';
$output .= '<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">Thanks & Regards,</p>';
$output .= '<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">South Post Fitness,</p>';
$output .= 'Phone: <a href="tel:416843 5925">(416) 843 5925</a><br>';
$output .='Email: <a href="maito: info@xx.com">info@xx.com</a>';
$output .= '</div></body></html>';

 $to = 'my email address here';  /* Receivers Email*/

$headers = "From: $email \r\n"; /*Headers*/
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; /*Headers*/
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n"; /*Headers*/

$subject = 'my subject here'; /* Subject */
mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers); /*Sending Mail*/
  if(mail) {
    if($cars=="Volvo"){
          header("Location: http://facebook.com");  /*Redirect to home after sucessfull submission*/
    }
    elseif($cars=="Saab"){
      header("Location: http://twitter.com");  /*Redirect to home after sucessfull submission*/
    }
    elseif($cars=="Audi"){
        header("Location: http://pintrest.com");  /*Redirect to home after sucessfull submission*/
    }
  }
  else {
  echo 'Error sending email'; /*If failed display error message */
  }

?>
```

But this code only redirecting page to first link i.e. facebook.com no matter which option is selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers); /*Sending Mail*/
if(mail) {
```

should probably be

```
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers); /*Sending Mail*/
if($mail) {
```

Note the missing variable assignment and the missing `$` symbol in your condition.

Over that you check against upper case strings but your actual string is lower case.

```
if($cars=="Volvo")
```

is not the same as

```
if($cars=="volvo")
```

Comment: Yeah it solved the issue, i was calling actual value as "Volvo" and "Saab" but not html value="saab" I have replaced code with $cars2=$cars; and then if($cars2=="volvo") with small "v" and its now working, i have not replaced any other code.

Answer (score 2):

The mail function has the return type bool, therefore you should use the result for your check:

```
$result = mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers);
if($result) {
    ...
}
```

String comparison with `==` should be avoided. Use `strcmp('string1', 'string2') == 0` for equality check.

If you change the last part of your code to use `strcmp` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Very short answer, but you are setting $cars from $_POST['cars'] and your select is posting all values, so change

```
 <select name="cars">
```

to

```
 <select name="cars[]">
```

That way you will get `$_POST['cars']` array with all values in it from your select. Else it will just post first `<option>`

**EDIT**

As another answer said you definitly should do `$mail_success = mail();`
as function mail() returns bool.
Then you can do a `if($mail_success) {}`

**EDIT 2**
Add `die;` after `header()` - else the script might continue and lead too unexpected behaviour.